# Cross domain request is not successful?

Tags: jquery

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://xxx/',
        type: 'GET',
        crossDomain:true,
        cache:true,
        dataType:"script",
        success:function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){

            alert(data);
        }
    }); 
});
```

actually server is returning json object and in my firebug it is showing 
SyntaxError: invalid label

What can I do ?

Comment: "invalid label" has no relation with cross domain errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server returns json, then you could not get the data even you set `crossDomain:true`.

If you want to crossDomain work, the server need to support JSONP, which is wrapping the json with a callback function.

Comment: Whith CORS headers, you may do JSON. You don't HAVE to use JSONP. But what OP's trying isn't clear.

Comment: @dystroy Yep, but this is not supported by all the browsers, so there come to JSONP.

Answer (score 1):

Try `dataType : "json"` instead of `dataType:"script"`

Answer (score 0):

hey i got the solutions for it

$.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : URL,
            dataType : "jsonp",
            jsonp : "jsoncallback",
            jsonpCallback : "SMS",
            cache : true,
            success : function(service_data) {
                bi(service_data);

```
        },
        error : function(msg) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
        }
    });
```